# How do I set a type of "any interface" in a given namespace?

Tags: typescript, redux

I am using Redux with TypeScript for the first time and would like to assign types to my actions, then bind those action types to an associated reducers action argument.

I have a namespace declared for some simple CRUD actions that looks like this:

```
// listings.actionTypes.ts

export namespace ListingActionTypes {
    export interface GetListingsAction {
        type: string
    }

    export interface GetListingsErrorAction {
        error: string
        type: string
    }

    export interface GetListingsSuccessAction {
        listings: Listing[]
        type: string
    }
}
```

My reducer file has a switch for each of these actions:

```
// listings.reducers.ts

const initialListingsState: [] = []

export const listingsReducer = (state: [] = initialListingsState, action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_LISTINGS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {})

        case 'GET_LISTINGS_ERROR':
            return Object.assign({}, state, { error: action.error })

        case 'GET_LISTINGS_SUCCESS':
            return Object.assign({}, state, { listings: action.listings })

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

What I am hoping to rectify is the `any` type on the `action: any` argument in my reducer's function signature.

My immediate thought process was that it would be as simple as asigning the action argument to the namespace (e.g. `action: ListingActionTypes`) but that seems to not be allowed as the compiler complains with the following error:

> Cannot use namespace 'ListingActionTypes' as a type.

Perhaps I am not supposed to use namespaces here? Any suggestions here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd specifically recommend switching to use [the `createSlice` function from our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice), which is intended to make it easy to define reducers and action creators while using TypeScript (and will also simplify your app code):

```
import {createSlice, PayloadAction} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export interface ListingsState {
  listings: Listing[];
  error?: string;
}

export const initialState : ListingsState = {
  listings: []
}

export const listingsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "listings",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getListings(state) {
      return {listings: []}; // TODO really reset the state here?
    },
    getListingsError(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
    getListingsSuccess(state, action: PayloadAction<Listing[]>) {
      state.listings = action.payload;
      state.error = undefined;
    }
  }
})
```